# semantic_form_for with an alert upon completion

Tags: ruby, formtastic

I am using semantic_form_for and I wonder if there is such attribute as :complete then upon successful creation, the form would alert something so that the user would have to click on "Okay" to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean confirmation before submit?

you could use something like the following:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @user do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= f.buttons do %>
      <%= f.commit_button :button_html => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'} %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is like the following and it works well:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @post do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.action :submit, :button_html => { 'data-confirm'.to_sym => 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```